# Search on DB during routine operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq, search, operation

I'm in a very difficult situation with search, SQL Server and routine operations.
Every two hours a program runs and for at least 5 minutes the search implemented on another program doesn't work because the routine operation cleans the main table where all data is stored and after some elaboration the table will be refilled with new data.

There is a optimal way to manage this 5 minutes?

We try swapping table or renaming them but the relations will be lost and missing data will be delete in cascade.

The best solution will make the data always reachable.
(the table have around 3,5 million rows)

Comment: What do you mean by "the routine operation cleans the main table"? Is old data being deleted? Is invalid data being updated? Are you able to modify this "cleans" process to mitigate the problems that it is causing?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to ensure that the routine operation cleans the table and repopulates using a transaction. Then in your code for searching, you'll need to set your `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` to `SNAPSHOT` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server).  This allows you to search for the data that was in there while the clean/refill operation is in progress.

Comment: Glad to hear! Would appreciate it if you upvoted this answer and marked it as the answer.

Comment: Done it but this message appeared: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded